# Creating a cookie in Windows Phone using InvokeScript

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, cookies, windows-phone, invokescript

I'm using trying to create a cookie in my WP8 app using the following code

```
private void setCookie(string value)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendFormat("document.cookie = '{0}={1}", "at", value);
        sb.AppendFormat(";path=/");
        sb.AppendFormat(";domain=mydomain.com'");
        var cookieJs = sb.ToString();
        Debug.WriteLine(cookieJs);
        webBrowser1.InvokeScript(cookieJs);
    }
```

The string I send in value is a series of chars 
and if I writhe it to a message box the sb returns the following `document.cookie = 'at=0b213kjsdf34e;path=/;domain=mydomain.com'`

but the `webBrowser1.InvokeScript(cookieJs);` throws a error. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: it say An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: looking in output i see the following The thread 0xff8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
A first chance exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll
An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", cookieJs);`